# $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ has a single eigenvalue over $\mathbb C$, then $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ $A$ is a scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So while playing with matrices a little, I found something that I think is true but I don't know how to prove in the general case. I tried to formalize it and this is the result:

> Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a square matrix such that it has a single eigenvalue over $\mathbb C$. Then $A$ is diagonalizable, if and only if, $A$ is a scalar matrix.

I succeeded proving this for both of the cases where $n=2$ and $n=3$ so I believe this might be true. Couldn't find a counterexample either.

Thanks!

Comment: For a diagonalizable matrix, the minimal polynomial (the roots of which are exactly the complex eigenvalues) has simple roots. So if a matrix with exactly one eigenvalue is diagonalizable, the minimal polynomial must have degree $1$ thus the matrix must be scalar.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a scalar matrix,  $A$ is diagonal,  hence diagonalizable.

Conversely,  if $A$ is diagonalizable,  then it is similar to a matrix with its eigenvalues on the diagonal.   If there's only one eigenvalue,  $A$ is scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is scalar then it's of course diagonalizable.

Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable; then its unique eigenvalue $\lambda$ must have geometric multiplicity $n$, which means that $A-\lambda I_n$ has rank $0$. Thus $A-\lambda I_n=0$.